# Ubuntu for moto luxe

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch

I have a Moto luxe that I wish change because its too slow.
Can I change my android on a Moto luxe cell phone for the Ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/05/ubuntu-touch-for-phones-to-be-usable-by-end-of-may all indications are Ubuntu Touch for the phone isn't ready for every day use yet. According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Porting Ubuntu Touch is basically runing on top of CyanogenMod, so if you device is supported at http://www.cyanogenmod.org/ is will probably support Ubuntu Touch.